# Multiple instances of SharePoint 2010 Service Applications per WebApp?

Tags: performancepoint, service-applications

In the [Services architecture planning (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc560988.aspx), in the section "Connecting to multiple Managed Metadata service applications" you can read the following:

> A service application group can include multiple Managed Metadata service applications.
>    For example, in the diagram of Farm C, the custom group that is highlighted in green
>    includes two Managed Metadata service applications.
>   In this scenario, the sites within the Web applications display taxonomy,
>   social tagging, and other features from both Managed Metadata service applications. 
>   Unlike other cross-farm services, Web parts by default include data from
>   multiple Managed Metadata service applications.

My question is now: what about other service applications, like i.e. PerformancePoint ?
Is it possible and supported to run multiple instances of service applications (other than Managed Metadata) per WebApplication ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK it it possible and supported to run multiple instances of all service applications per WebApplication, but also AFAIK Managed Metadata is the only one where the OOTB functionality can take advantage of it.